# VideoJS 4 native controls now default on mobile?

Tags: mobile, native, video.js

I am adapting my resolution switching work for Vidcaster on VideoJS into a plugin (see https://github.com/videojs/video.js/pull/233).

In VideoJS 3.2 the VideoJS controls were active on mobile platforms such as Android and iOS.  Now when I boot up version 4 it appears the native controls take precedence.  This means that features that require actions on control bar buttons such as tracks, etc are not accessible, correct?

We would like to continue to present a resolution switching button to our mobile users.  Was the decision to defer to the native controls an intentional philosophical one?  If so, where in the code does this decision happen?  I have been digging for it for a while now.

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to the [source](https://github.com/videojs/video.js/blob/32519181c8ffacbc2b322e42958a2db4a5fb4d3c/src/js/player.js#L27-36) the native controls are default on iOS and Android "until controls are more stable on those devices".

`<video data-setup='{"customControlsOnMobile": true}' …` would enable the video.js controls, but bear in mind they're disabled for a reason.

**Update:** This question and answer relate to video.js 4. For video.js 5 the equivalent is `nativeControlsForTouch: false`. Native controls are always used on iPhone and older versions of Android known to be problematic with custom controls.

Comment: Ah, that option was added after I cloned the repo so I didn't find it.  While it seems like the right answer, that option alone does not seem to do anything, at least on iOS.  I will have to spend more time playing with options and reading the source.  It's possible VideoJS just doesn't support rendering menus on mobile at the moment.

Comment: My data-setup was actually invalid JSON (always quote keys!), so the options never got parsed properly.  You are correct - this does enable the VideoJS controls on mobile.

Answer (score 5):

Currently the option to initialize a video that will display videojs' custom controls and not the native controls (iOS, for example) is `nativeControlsForTouch: false`. 
Can be found in the source [here](https://github.com/videojs/video.js/blob/0f38d27dcc4cc56d011dea1620bac7b73ac2b17b/src/js/player.js#L54).
This option can be set as stated in the answer above through `<video data-setup='{"nativeControlsForTouch": false}' …` or through JavaScript: `vjs('video_id', {nativeControlsForTouch: false});`

Comment: Thanks for this @jweilder.  I didn't know about this feature.

Tested this via Browserstack using Video.js v4.5.1. Here's what I found:

**iOS 7+**
Works.

**iOS 5.0 - 6.0**
Works, but reloading the page brings back native controls.  I imagine native controls would show again on a revisit to the page assuming it's cached by the browser.
 
**iOS 4.3.2 and below**
Does not work.