# On iPads, easier to hide native control bar or hide videoJS control bar?

Tags: ipad, html5-video

In video-js.css, I have set .vjs-control-bar to bottom:-36px, which places it below the video, and `visibility: visible;` and `opacity: 1;` so it never fades. That's how I want it, but on iPads, the Quicktime control-bar inserts itself on the video (and fades, but reappears on touch). Both work.

After reading this - https://github.com/videojs/video.js/issues/1096 - I tried changing `nativeControlsForTouch!==1)` to `nativeControlsForTouch!==0)` - I'm assuming "0" = "false" - but the QT controls are still there. Does anyone have a way of hiding the iPad controls?

Alternative - is there a way to hide the videojs control-bar, but only on mobiles with native players, not on PCs that don't?

**UPDATE**

I can hide the QT control bar on iPad 7 by adding `data-setup='{"nativeControlsForTouch": false}'`... to the video tag, but that doesn't work with video.js, only with video.dev.js, where I find `if (vjs.TOUCH_ENABLED && player.options()['nativeControlsForTouch'] !== false)`. In video.js I find: `nativeControlsForTouch!==0`).

If I delete that data-setup from the video tag, it has both control bars with video.dev.js as well.   I'm no expert - what's going on?

Here's links to the files:

- http://www.casedasole.it/testing/video/demo.html
- http://www.casedasole.it/testing/video/video.js
- http://www.casedasole.it/testing/video/video.dev.js

Answer (score 0):

Try using `<video data-setup='{"customControlsOnMobile": true}' …`. This is false by default and controls whether the video.js controls will be shown instead of native.

Comment: Tried it, but no luck. QT controls still there. Also, I don't find "customControlsOnMobile" in v4.6.2 of video.js. There is this suggestion - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16697473/videojs-4-native-controls-now-default-on-mobile - to use data-setup='{"nativeControlsForTouch": false}' but had no efect either in  iOS 7.